# How is Lobo able to regenerate the way he does?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe

The character Lobo seems to have incredible regenerative abilities- from at least one comic and his appearance on an episode of the second season of Krypton, he was able to reconstitute himself after being outright dismembered. If the rest of his species is dead, how is he able to perform these feats?

Answer (score 6):

Lobo's regeneration seems to be the result of being a [Czarnian](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Czarnians), a race of immortals. As to how he was able to kill the rest of his species (he missed one who was off-world), [his high school science project](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Lobo_(New_Earth)#History) was to develop a scorpion-like breed of creatures that would inflict incredible agony on any Czarnian that was stung, essentially poisoning them in a way in which they chose to die.

> Inspired by the idea of genocide, Lobo created a swarm of lethal scorpion-like creatures, he set them on his people wiping out his entire species but himself. He claimed it was a science project and gave himself an 'A'.

[image: Image of Lobo unleashing the creatures]